# php for "selected feature" - Combination of Openlayers and php-Form

Tags: openlayers-2, php

I use a postgres db, geoserver and openlayers to display a map with a wfs-t Layer that displays the geometry column of my table.
Now I use control select to call a popup which contains a form to edit the other attribute-columns, e.g.:

```
    //add Popup
var select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(garden);
        map.addControl(select);
        select.activate();

garden.events.on({
   featureselected: function(event) {
    var feature = event.feature;
    feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud
    ("pop",
    feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
    null, 
    <form action="myphp.php" method="post">
    <div class="label"> Crop:</div><input name="crop" type="text" value=+feature.attributes.crop+>
    <input type="submit" name="write">
    </form>);
 map.addPopup(feature.popup);  
},
```

In my php-script I wrote:

```
$crop= $_POST['crop'];
```

and:

```
$res = pg_query ("UPDATE $tabelle SET crop = '".pg_escape_string ($crop)."' WHERE id = 6;");
```

This works fine, editing a specific line, in this case the line where the "id=6".

**My Question**: What is the php-Code for sth. like "where the id= selected feature id".
How can I replace the "WHERE id = 6"-part with a variable that says: always update the attributes of the selected polygon"?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is you that first need to get the selected id of the feature using OpenLayers. 
Then in the HTML form you can put that value into an hidden field, something like :

```
                 <input type="hidden" name="myhiddenfield" value="feature.id" />
```

You'll be able to retrieve It in PHP after using 
                         $_POST['myhiddenfield']

Hope that helps, 
Gallien L.